# Xcode build failed for Particle photon tinker ios from Github release v1.6_appstore

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Got source from: Github > spark/photon-tinker-ios > Releases > v1.6_appstore

Tried to build on Xcode 7.3.1 on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 MacBook Pro

Got build error:
"Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11"

v1.6 from Apple app store runs fine on my iPhone6+.

BUILD LOG:

Write auxiliary files

write-file /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/swift-overrides.hmap
write-file /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/Script-9349E507210B5FCF0E40908B.sh
chmod 0755 /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/Script-9349E507210B5FCF0E40908B.sh
write-file /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/Particle-all-target-headers.hmap
/bin/mkdir -p /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/Objects-normal/x86_64
write-file /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Particle.LinkFileList
write-file /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/Particle-own-target-headers.hmap
write-file /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Particle-OutputFileMap.json
write-file /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/Script-E7199E700B0E368CCC6643CB.sh
chmod 0755 /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/Script-E7199E700B0E368CCC6643CB.sh
write-file /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/Particle.hmap
write-file /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/Particle-generated-files.hmap
write-file /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/Script-4993386E974D210DB907EAD3.sh
chmod 0755 /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/Script-4993386E974D210DB907EAD3.sh
write-file /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/Particle-project-headers.hmap
write-file /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/Particle-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap

Create product structure

/bin/mkdir -p /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.app

PhaseScriptExecution Check\ Pods\ Manifest.lock /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/Script-9349E507210B5FCF0E40908B.sh
    cd /Primary/PROJECTS/DvineWave/_REFERENCE_2016/photon-tinker-ios-1.6_appstore
    /bin/sh -c /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/Script-9349E507210B5FCF0E40908B.sh

CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
    cd /Primary/PROJECTS/DvineWave/_REFERENCE_2016/photon-tinker-ios-1.6_appstore
    export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk
    export TOOLCHAINS=com.apple.dt.toolchain.iOS9_3
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc -incremental -module-name Particle -Onone -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk -target x86_64-apple-ios8.0 -g -module-cache-path /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -Xfrontend -serialize-debugging-options -enable-testing -I /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -c -j8 /Primary/PROJECTS/DvineWave/_REFERENCE_2016/photon-tinker-ios-1.6_appstore/Photon-Tinker/SettingsTableViewController.swift /Primary/PROJECTS/DvineWave/_REFERENCE_2016/photon-tinker-ios-1.6_appstore/Photon-Tinker/DeviceListViewController.swift /Primary/PROJECTS/DvineWave/_REFERENCE_2016/photon-tinker-ios-1.6_appstore/Photon-Tinker/WelcomeViewController.swift /Primary/PROJECTS/DvineWave/_REFERENCE_2016/photon-tinker-ios-1.6_appstore/Photon-Tinker/AppDelegate.swift /Primary/PROJECTS/DvineWave/_REFERENCE_2016/photon-tinker-ios-1.6_appstore/Photon-Tinker/ElectronSetupViewController.swift /Primary/PROJECTS/DvineWave/_REFERENCE_2016/photon-tinker-ios-1.6_appstore/Photon-Tinker/DeviceTableViewCell.swift /Primary/PROJECTS/DvineWave/_REFERENCE_2016/photon-tinker-ios-1.6_appstore/Photon-Tinker/WebViewController.swift -output-file-map /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Particle-OutputFileMap.json -parseable-output -serialize-diagnostics -emit-dependencies -emit-module -emit-module-path /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Particle.swiftmodule -Xcc -I/Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/Particle-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/Particle-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/Particle-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/Particle-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Primary/PROJECTS/DvineWave/_REFERENCE_2016/photon-tinker-ios-1.6_appstore/Pods/Headers/Public -Xcc -I/Primary/PROJECTS/DvineWave/_REFERENCE_2016/photon-tinker-ios-1.6_appstore/Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking -Xcc -I/Primary/PROJECTS/DvineWave/_REFERENCE_2016/photon-tinker-ios-1.6_appstore/Pods/Headers/Public/ASValueTrackingSlider -Xcc -I/Primary/PROJECTS/DvineWave/_REFERENCE_2016/photon-tinker-ios-1.6_appstore/Pods/Headers/Public/HexColors -Xcc -I/Primary/PROJECTS/DvineWave/_REFERENCE_2016/photon-tinker-ios-1.6_appstore/Pods/Headers/Public/Keys -Xcc -I/Primary/PROJECTS/DvineWave/_REFERENCE_2016/photon-tinker-ios-1.6_appstore/Pods/Headers/Public/MBProgressHUD -Xcc -I/Primary/PROJECTS/DvineWave/_REFERENCE_2016/photon-tinker-ios-1.6_appstore/Pods/Headers/Public/Mixpanel -Xcc -I/Primary/PROJECTS/DvineWave/_REFERENCE_2016/photon-tinker-ios-1.6_appstore/Pods/Headers/Public/PullToRefreshCoreText -Xcc -I/Primary/PROJECTS/DvineWave/_REFERENCE_2016/photon-tinker-ios-1.6_appstore/Pods/Headers/Public/Spark-SDK -Xcc -I/Primary/PROJECTS/DvineWave/_REFERENCE_2016/photon-tinker-ios-1.6_appstore/Pods/Headers/Public/SparkSetup -Xcc -I/Primary/PROJECTS/DvineWave/_REFERENCE_2016/photon-tinker-ios-1.6_appstore/Pods/Headers/Public/TSMessages -Xcc -I/Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -emit-objc-header -emit-objc-header-path /Users/douglaskbell/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Particle-ehfqqsfqxyudnggpazkmheybqkkr/Build/Intermediates/Particle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Particle.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Particle-Swift.h -import-objc-header /Primary/PROJECTS/DvineWave/_REFERENCE_2016/photon-tinker-ios-1.6_appstore/Photon-Tinker/SparkSetup-Bridging-Header.h -Xcc -working-directory/Primary/PROJECTS/DvineWave/_REFERENCE_2016/photon-tinker-ios-1.6_appstore

:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
:0: error: compile command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
:0: error: compile command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
:0: error: compile command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
:0: error: compile command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
:0: error: compile command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
:0: error: compile command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
:0: error: compile command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Can you share the log or something so we can check what the actual issue is. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26557581/command-failed-due-to-signal-segmentation-fault-11

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32645533/xcode-7-compile-error-command-failed-due-to-signal-segmentation-fault-11

can help

Comment: I added the build log (transcript). I read above link.  Possible problem may be that Particle's Tinker app may not be up to date with latest Xcode 7.3.1 that I'm using.