# Xcode 8 random command failed due to signal segmentation fault 11

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, segmentation-fault, swift3

I have a strange problem with the new Xcode 8 (no beta version) and swift3.

Once every other 3-4 times that I compile my code I get a 'command failed due to signal segmentation fault 11' error. I just need to enter new empty line, or sometimes changing some spaces, or add a comment (everywhere in the code) and the error disappears and I can compile again.
This is really strange because I'm not changing anything in the code! And sometimes I can compile and it works, then I don't change anything, I compile again and I get the error.
This is really annoying!

I have noticed this is happening since I have installed several 'Firebase' pods (Firebase, Firebase/Auth etc...). But I need them.

Anyone has any suggestion?

PS: I have set the Enable Bitcode of my project to No as many solution suggested, but nothing. In the error message it is not indicated any swift page where the error can be, an example is:

1. While loading members for 'Class_name' at
2. While deserializing 'func_name' (FuncDecl #42)

'func_name' is this one:

```
public class func loginUser(fir_user: FIRUser) {
    let user = SFUser()
    user.email = fir_user.email 
    user.isLogged = true
    try! sfRealm.write() {
        sfRealm.add(user, update:true)
    }

    var userToAdd = [String:AnyObject]()
    userToAdd["email"] = fir_user.email! as NSString

    let ref=FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let usersRef = ref.child(childName)
    usersRef.setValue([key:value])
}
```

But then, as I said, I can just enter an empty row in another file and it compiles!

Thanks

Comment: good to know that such kind of errors persists on XCode8 ... :(

Comment: If you uninstall those pods do you still get the error message (If you compile 3-4 times)?

Comment: @Andrea Please post the solution you found as an answer, since your problem seems resolved.

Comment: @Dev-iL thank you, just done :)

Comment: This may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32645533/xcode-7-compile-error-command-failed-due-to-signal-segmentation-fault-11?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: i faced the same and i update my xcode 8.2.1 to 8.3 and error is gone. you can get latest xcode from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-4-5-6-7-8-and-get-the-dmg-or-xip-file

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue i just figure out that i was using xcode 8.1 and the project's working copy was in xcode 8.2.1 so i just re install xcode 8.2.1 and problem got solved. Hope other can get the help trough this.

Comment: i also tried re intall xcode 8.2.1, when i just open the project it was working correctly, but after few minutes of coding it started showing this error and whole code editor's font becomes black color ( i mean Code Editor can't recognise / identify those syntex ).

Comment: @Vats Well i am agree for that but some times pc restart or xcode restart works for the problem. but i hadn't face this issue yet after that replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that I have found the solution: it is a problem with Firebase and cocoapods, so 2 solutions:

Download Firebase and import into your project

I, instead, updated cocoapods to the last version and it worked. Upgraded Firebase - Now Getting Swift Compile Error

Comment: I am getting this error and I have never used cocoapods (bad me?) so while problems with cocoapods may cause this error, it can happen without cocoapods.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was some type checking issue deep down the compiler so the editor didn't give error in the gutter but on building the project I was getting signal setmentation fault 11 error:

```
1.  While type-checking 'GetStoreAPIRequestModel' at /Users/.../StoreAPIModel.swift:9:1
2.  While type-checking expression at [/Users/.../StoreAPIModel.swift:15:18 - line:15:31] RangeText="[Dictionary]()"
3.  While resolving type [Dictionary] at [/Users/.../StoreAPIModel.swift:15:18 - line:15:29] RangeText="[Dictionary]"
```

So I changed my code from:

```
var stores = [Dictionary]() {
        willSet {
            allStores.removeAll()

            for model in newValue {
                allStores.append(StoreAPIModel(dictionary: model as! Dictionary).getModel())
            }
        }
    }
```

To (more descriptive dictionary):

```
var stores = [[String : Any]]() {
        willSet {
            allStores.removeAll()

            for model in newValue {
                allStores.append(StoreAPIModel(dictionary: model as [String : AnyObject]).getModel())
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: After your build failed, where did you find the 1/2/3 messages you show?

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky problem. Issue can be with line of code or syntax. I was getting similar error and it was due to incorrect usage of dictionary. I was trying to increment the value of dictionary element.

Solution is to triage the code, detailed error provide which module has issue, so try commenting part of code until you find the line which is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i had the same issue with FireBase , my problem was that i was extending `FIRStorageReference` and `FIRDatabaseReference` and some time it compile successfully some time i get

> command failed due to signal segmentation fault 11

so i removed that files and implement the method other way , now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem when this occurred. (No cocoapods.) I thought I had left the program in a working state, but I was wrong. I am writing a straightforward command-line program. What it does is somewhat general, so I defined all the strings that make it specific in `let` statements at the top of the program so that I could someday use the program in a different context.

Since that was working so well, I thought I'd be clever and do the same with a filter of an array of dictionaries. I turned:

```
list.filter { $0["SearchStrings"] == nil }
```

into:

```
let test = { $0["SearchStrings"] == nil }
// ...
list.filter(test)
```

meaning to continue working on the `let`, but I never went back and did that. Building gave me the segmentation fault error. Defining `test` as a function fixed the problem.

(Incidentally, I understand how to strip a filtering function down to the terse braces notation in the context of the call to `Array.filter`, and why that works, but I don't understand why I can't assign the brace expression to a constant and use it as such.)