# Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 swift 3

Tags: ios, debugging, swift3, xcode8

just updated my Xcode and got this error in one of my previous project i searched around a bit and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32645533/xcode-7-compile-error-command-failed-due-to-signal-segmentation-fault-11) question 
 according to that question  this is Xcode bug. i dont have any idea how to fix it cause the error message is not giving me any clue about the error and why its occurring. so far what i have is this :

```
Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
```

and error's logs contains [this](http://pastebin.com/TVRPFJaP) class's name and this class is the part of

[this Library](https://github.com/dogo/SCLAlertView)

anyone have faced any similar problem ??

i got some lead . my error is pointing to a line :

```
 While emitting IR SIL function @_TFC12SCLAlertView12SCLAlertView16viewDidDisappearfSbT_ for 'viewDidDisappear' at mydirectorytoproject/mProject/Pods/SCLAlertView/SCLAlertView/SCLAlertView.swift:379:19
```

here's the line 379 on my class:

```
override open func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide)
```

}

Comment: Me! My experience is that that may not be the line which is causing the problem. Try commenting out sections of the method and compiling. Maybe the constants have lowercase forms

Comment: @HongWei please check the updated question i mentioned wrong lines sorry my bad

Answer (score 2):

I think your observer is wrong. You are putting the notification name instead of the observer:

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow)
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide)
```

Try something like if your observer is the current class:

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
```

Also, I think you do not need `open` in `override open func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool)`

Answer (score 0):

I think , You are added same file two times in your Project.

Check all the files and remove.

i think it will help you because it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue now.
You should use `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)` in your `deinit` or `viewDidDisappear` methods.