# Segmentation Fault: 11 Swift 2

Tags: swift2, xcode7

I updated my iOS swift app to Swift 2 syntax. I solved all the errors as requested but the App does not compile at all. Instead I get this crazy error that I've never seen before:

[image]

What does this mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11 swift frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007755/unable-to-execute-command-segmentation-fault-11-swift-frontend-command-failed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a compiler bug - the Swift compiler is crashing.

What you need to do is reduce the source file to only the lines that cause the segmentation fault and then you need to raise a bug report at Apple attaching the source file that causes the crash,

https://bugreport.apple.com

There may be an error in your code that is triggering the bug, but, nevertheless, the compiler should not crash.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot reveals that the errors are related to error handling.
Update your code to use the new error handling syntax like

```
do {
 try someFunctionThatCanThrow()
 // do something on success
} catch let error as NSError {
 // do something on error
}
```

The error listing displays the code and the line where the error occurs for each error.

Comment: These are other errors related for upgrading from swift 1 to swift 2. I had changed all my error handling code according to the new swift 2 do-try-catch and I still have segmentation fault 11

Comment: All errors are pretty well described in the error listing