# Segmentation fault: 11 swift Xcode 10.2.1

Tags: swift, xcode

I am getting "[Segmentation fault: 1]" error after updating my pod file also "Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code" error. How to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Try to clean and re-build the project.**

1. Clean:
   <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
2. Build: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

Comment: This might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007755/unable-to-execute-command-segmentation-fault-11-swift-frontend-command-failed