# Xcode 6 under yosemite crash

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6, osx-yosemite-beta

When i try to run any project on any DEVICE (not simulator) on any iOS in Xcode 6 (any version including 6.0.1 and all betas) under yosemite Xcode crashes right after "Build succeeded".
the log shows:

```
Application Specific Information:

ProductBuildVersion: 6A317

ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-6528/DVTFoundation/FilePaths/DVTFilePath.m:802

Details: fsrep is relative ('גÄ‮-‬‭/‬גÄ‮,‬var/folders/dv/c6tb8vv93tj99rmr6t85znt80000gn/CגÄ‮-‬‭/‬גÄ‮,‬‭/‬com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0.1‭/‬Xcode') 

parentPath must not be nil but it is.

Object: <DVTFilePath>

Method:+_filePathForParent:fileSystemRepresentation:length:allowCreation:

Thread: <NSThread: 0x7fd923ee3000> {number = 20, name = (null)}

Hints:None
```

I tried to delete the com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist & reinstall Xcode but it keeps crashing on devices,
On simulator it works.

Help please.

Comment: Report it to Apple; they are both in beta.

Comment: I wonder does it have something to do with `גÄ‮-‬‭/‬גÄ‮,‬`

Comment: same issue here. I have tried both Xcode 6.0 GM and Xcode 6.1 beta 2.

Comment: Xcode 6.0.1 on Mavericks works fine for me, have yet to experience a crash. Probably is a Yosemite issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution for me was to remove Urdu language from the list (System preferences>Language and Region). It was set as primary. I kept only English and after restarting Xcode is not crashing anymore.

Comment: Thank you it worked for me. I hope apple will fix this bug so i can use my language as the primary language.

Comment: thank you. that made it work. like @OlegSh.I hope this gets fixed soon, I'd want to use Urdu as my primary language

Comment: after 2 days of going here and there finally I found this and it worked. You are my hero :)

Answer (score 12):

Try to exit fullscreen mode in Xcode and run your app again. It was crashing for me when Xcode was in fullscreen mode.

This is Xcode 6.0 with OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Looks like that solved the issue. Full-screen worked on pre-Yosemite OSX, though. Hopefully we'll see an update soon. XCode Version 6.0.1 (6A317)

Answer (score 0):

It seems a lot of people are having trouble with Xcode 6 and Yosemite but are reporting that the new Xcode beta is resolving the issues.  Xcode 6.1 beta 2 just came out a couple days ago so perhaps you should try that if you haven't already.

Remove your current version of Xcode and it may also help to delete the `AppleMobileDevice.kext` file in `/System/Library/Extensions` as well as `AppleMobileDeviceSupport.pkg` in `/Library/Receipts/` and then download and use the [Xcode 6.1 beta 2](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09152014a)

---

If you read the error it says that the path is being read as nil because it's got those unusual characters `גÄ‮-‬‭/‬גÄ` .. Track down the cache files for this reference and delete them.

Comment: i already have xcode 6.1 beta 2. let me try deleting everything and see if it works. Thanks

Comment: did the above, now project won't compile (segfault): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222644/swift-compiler-segmentation-fault-when-building

Comment: after removing the code causing segfaults, the problem is still there. Thank you for the pointers though, may come in handy.