# Get TestFlight logging and crash symbolication for Swift apps

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6

I can upload and distribute swift apps builds via test flight just fine. I have been integrating TestFlight SDK via bridging header too. However, my crash logs aren't symbolicated e.g. I am getting this:

```
3   libswiftCore.dylib  0x1004f368b swift_bridgeNonVerbatimFromObjectiveC
4   xcode-project   0x1000c00c7 _TFC13xcode_project16ContactsImporter12copyContactsfMS0_FT_GSaCS_4User_
5   xcode-project   0x1000bfdb3 _TFC13xcode_project16ContactsImporter14importContactsfMS0_FFGSaCS_4User_T_T_
6   xcode-project   0x1000b64a3 _TFC13xcode_project30PrezzeeContainerViewController9tableViewfS0_FTGSQCSo11UITableView_23didSelectRowAtIndexPathGSQCSo11NSIndexPath__T_
7   UIKit   0x18d794857
```

Since [apparently yosemite won't let my xcode deploy apps on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25904414/xcode-6-under-yosemite-crash), TestFlight's crash logging would have been helpful in resolving this

Also, in objective C, I could redefine NSLog and all my logs would appear on TestFlight, how do I do that for Swift?