# Using NSLayoutConstraint extension causes SourceKitService crash

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to use convenience init for `NSLayoutConstraint` that is specified in the documentation - https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLayoutConstraint/constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:

the moment I paste the code into `NSLayoutConstraint`, I start receiving:

```
SourceKitService crashed.
```

After researching the Stack Overflow for similar problems I found out that the problem is quite common and that no solution has been found to the day:
[SourceKitService Terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006206/sourcekitservice-terminated)

When I try to build the code, ignoring the fact that the code doesn't have syntax highlighting, the compiler returns:

```
Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault:11
```

So I followed this lead, and found out that sometimes, having extensions in one file instead of separate files, helps. It didn't in my case
[Swift compiler segmentation fault when building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222644/swift-compiler-segmentation-fault-when-building)

Can someone provide me with any tips that can lead to fixing Swift's extensions problems for `NSLayoutConstraint`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. File a bug report and wait for the Swift and Xcode team to fix the issue.