# Swift compiler error on Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift, compiler-errors

I have problems with Swift Compiler:
I created new project for iOs on latest Xcode 6 and tried to build - recieved 2 errors with ViewController.swift and AppDelegate.swift.

```
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
<unknown>:0: error: swift frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
<unknown>:0: error: unable to execute command: Bus error: 10 
<unknown>:0: error: swift frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
```

I can post a full logs if if it is necessary.

What should i do? Thanks.

Comment: The compiler should not crash even if the input is wrong. Send a bug report to Apple.

Comment: I don't know enough about swift or your code (so I don't know if they are duplicates), but if you search for `Swift segmentation fault 11`  there are 3 *other* questions like yours, and at least one of them has an answer that shows a syntax error that triggers the fault. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222644/swift-compiler-segmentation-fault-when-building)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced a similar issue while working with a swift project. I found [this](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT2433) on Apple Support Website. It says that this type of error occurs when you tried to access an non-existent/inaccessible memory address. To solve the issue you can quit unused applications or even restart the mac which will probably help you.