# Segmentation Fault, Project is not getting built on Xcode 10 and Mojave.

Tags: ios, segmentation-fault, xcode10, macos-mojave

I am working on an iOS application that uses several third party frameworks.The project was running fine on **X-Code 9.3.1** running on **High Sierra** but when i updated my macOS to **Mojave** and X-Code to **version 10.0** the compiler started throwing the following error while linking the libraries:

```
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried all of the solutions posted for questions related to segmentation fault but unfortunately none of them worked.I tried using the X-Code 9.3.1 where the project was getting compiled with no issues on High Sierra but got the same errros on Mojave.The following is the complete error message from X-Code.

```
Ld /Users/raghavendra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Controller-befvgrmcpngvshariigzvmibtnhx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Controller-dbg.app/Controller-dbg normal arm64
    cd /Users/raghavendra/Ava_Spark_Bit_bucket_copy
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.3
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.3.sdk -L/Users/raghavendra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Controller-befvgrmcpngvshariigzvmibtnhx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/raghavendra/Ava_Spark_Bit_bucket_copy/ThirdParty -F/Users/raghavendra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Controller-befvgrmcpngvshariigzvmibtnhx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/raghavendra/Ava_Spark_Bit_bucket_copy/ThirdParty -F/Users/raghavendra/Documents/JabberSDK -F/Users/raghavendra/Ava_Spark_Bit_bucket_copy/SPARK\ frameworks -filelist /Users/raghavendra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Controller-befvgrmcpngvshariigzvmibtnhx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Controller.build/Debug-iphoneos/Controller.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Controller-dbg.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -map -Xlinker /Users/raghavendra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Controller-befvgrmcpngvshariigzvmibtnhx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Controller.build/Debug-iphoneos/Controller.build/Controller-dbg-LinkMap-normal-arm64.txt -miphoneos-version-min=9.3 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/raghavendra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Controller-befvgrmcpngvshariigzvmibtnhx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Controller.build/Debug-iphoneos/Controller.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Controller-dbg_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -fprofile-instr-generate -stdlib=libc++ -ObjC -framework Reveal -lModelObjects -framework Fabric -lBaseDataModelObject -framework Crashlytics -framework VSTheme -framework KeychainItemWrapper -framework MBProgressHUD -framework MessageUI -framework PullableView -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework MBProgressHUD -framework CoreGraphics -framework CocoaLumberjack -framework EventKit -framework WebSockets -framework QuartzCore -framework NetworkReachability -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/raghavendra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Controller-befvgrmcpngvshariigzvmibtnhx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Controller.build/Debug-iphoneos/Controller.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Controller-dbg_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/raghavendra/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Controller-befvgrmcpngvshariigzvmibtnhx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Controller-dbg.app/Controller-dbg

clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please help me resolve this issue.your inputs are highly appreciated.

Comment: you need to add all framework again in new Xcode remove all frameworks and add again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222644/swift-compiler-segmentation-fault-when-building this link might help

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @NoProb. My project doesn't have swift code but will try the solutions posted in the link.